# Стек - доработка по коду, питон. Нужна помощь!

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, стек

Пытался исправить две ошибки, на которые указал наставник(ниже опишу их) - и после какого-то момента, перестал работать весь код, вылезает тупо 3 traceback'a. Прошу помощи, в исправлении ошибок(я думаю, что они достаточно легкие, но не понимаю, как их вылить в код).

---

Ошибки:

***Строка 29:***                 `stack.push(int(element))`

*Для работы Калькулятора не важна конкретная функция, превращающая "строки в числа" (оцифровщик).
Поэтому лучше сделать универсальнее.
Пусть решающая функция получает "оцифровщик" необязательным параметром, у которого умолчание int.
Тогда калькулятор сможет работать и с числами типа float/complex/Decimal/Rational/...*

Строка 8:9 -

```
def pop(self):
    self.items.pop()
```

*Нужен страхующий код, так как этот вызов может сбоить*

---

**Задача:**
Задание связано с обратной польской нотацией. Она используется для парсинга арифметических выражений. Еще её иногда называют постфиксной нотацией.
В постфиксной нотации операнды расположены перед знаками операций.
Пример 1:

```
3 4 +
означает 3 + 4 и равно 7
```

Пример 2:

```
12 5 /
Так как деление целочисленное, то в результате получим 2.
Пример 3: 
10 2 4 * -
означает 10 - 2 * 4 и равно 2
```

Разберём последний пример подробнее:

Знак * стоит сразу после чисел 2 и 4, значит к ним нужно применить операцию, которую этот знак обозначает, то есть перемножить эти два числа. В результате получим 8.
После этого выражение приобретёт вид:

```
10 8 -
```

Операцию «минус» нужно применить к двум идущим перед ней числам, то есть 10 и 8. В итоге получаем 2.

Рассмотрим алгоритм более подробно. Для его реализации будем использовать стек.
Для вычисления значения выражения, записанного в обратной польской нотации, нужно считывать выражение слева направо и придерживаться следующих шагов:
Обработка входного символа:

Если на вход подан операнд, он помещается на вершину стека.

Если на вход подан знак операции, то эта операция выполняется над требуемым количеством значений, взятых из стека в порядке добавления. Результат выполненной операции помещается на вершину стека.

Если входной набор символов обработан не полностью, перейти к шагу 1.
После полной обработки входного набора символов результат вычисления выражения находится в вершине стека. Если в стеке осталось несколько чисел, то надо вывести только верхний элемент.

Замечание про отрицательные числа и деление: в этой задаче под делением понимается математическое целочисленное деление. Это значит, что округление всегда происходит вниз. А именно: если a / b = c, то b ⋅ c — это наибольшее число, которое не превосходит a и одновременно делится без остатка на b.
Например, -1 / 3 = -1. Будьте осторожны: в C++, Java и Go, например, деление чисел работает иначе.
В текущей задаче гарантируется, что деления на отрицательное число нет.

---

**Формат ввода**

В единственной строке дано выражение, записанное в обратной польской нотации. Числа и арифметические операции записаны через пробел.
На вход могут подаваться операции: `+, -, *, /` и числа, по модулю не превосходящие 10000.
Гарантируется, что значение промежуточных выражений в тестовых данных по модулю не больше 50000.

---

**Формат вывода**

Выведите единственное число — значение выражения.

---

***Пример 1:***

Ввод:

```
2 1 + 3 *
```

Вывод:

```
9
```

***Пример 2:***

Ввод:

```
7 2 + 4 * 2 +
```

Вывод:

```
38
```

---

Мой код:

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def push(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def pop(self): - 8:9
        self.items.pop()

    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)


OPERATORS = {'+': lambda x, y: x + y,
             '-': lambda x, y: x - y,
             '*': lambda x, y: x * y,
             '/': lambda x, y: x // y}


def calculator(line, stack=None, operators=OPERATORS):
    stack = Stack() if stack is None else stack
    for element in line:
        if element in operators:
            el1, el2 = stack.pop(), stack.pop()
            stack.push(operators[element](el1, el1))
        else:
            try:
                stack.push(int(element)) - 29 строка
            except:
                raise KeyError('WRONG_KEY')
    return stack.pop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    line = input().split()
    print(calculator(line))
```

---

Ошибки при выводе кода:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "final_b_13.py", line 37, in <module>
    print(calculator(line))
  File "final_b_13.py", line 26, in calculator
    stack.push(operators[element](el1, el1))
  File "final_b_13.py", line 15, in <lambda>
    OPERATORS = {'+': lambda x, y: x + y,
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первая ошибка - забыли `return` в функции `Stack.pop()`.
Вторая ошибка - арифметическую операцию проводите с одним и тем же элементом. Надо `stack.push(operators[element](el2, el1))`, а у вас `el1, el1`.

Остальную доработку см в коде:

```
import math

class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def push(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def pop(self): #- 8:9
        try:
            return self.items.pop()
        except IndexError:
            raise IndexError('Недостаточно операндов для вычисления.')

    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)


OPERATORS = {'+': lambda x, y: x + y,
             '-': lambda x, y: x - y,
             '*': lambda x, y: x * y,
             '/': lambda x, y: x / y,
             '%': lambda x, y: x % y,
             '^': lambda x, y: x ** y}

def MyInt(value):
    if isinstance(value, str):
        return int(value)
    return math.floor(value)

def calculator(line, stack=None, converter=int, operators=OPERATORS):
    stack = Stack() if stack is None else stack
    for element in line:
        if element in operators:
            el1, el2 = stack.pop(), stack.pop()
            try:
                stack.push(converter(operators[element](el2, el1)))
            except ZeroDivisionError:
                raise ZeroDivisionError(f'Деление на 0 при вычислении "{el2} {element} {el1}".')
            except TypeError:
                raise TypeError(f'Неподдерживаемая операция "{element}" для типа {converter.__name__}.')
        else:
            try:
                stack.push(converter(element)) #- 29 строка
            except:
                raise KeyError(f'Невозможно преобразовать "{element}" в {converter.__name__} или неподдерживаемая операция.')
    if stack.size() > 1:
        raise IndexError('Некорректное выражение - в стеке остались элементы.')
    return stack.pop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from decimal import Decimal
    #line = input().split()
    for line in ("10 2 4 * -", "12 5 /", "-1 3 /", "1.5 3.7 + 2.1 *", "2+3j -5-7j *", "2 3 ^ 3 %", "2 0 /", "1 2 3 +", "1 2 + *"):
        print(f'\n Выражение : "{line}"')
        line = line.split()
        for t in (int, MyInt, float, complex, Decimal):
            print(f"{t.__name__:>10} = ", end='')
            try:
                print(calculator(line, converter=t))
            except (KeyError, IndexError, ZeroDivisionError, TypeError) as err:
                print("Ошибка!", err)
```

```
 Выражение : "10 2 4 * -"
       int = 2
     MyInt = 2
     float = 2.0
   complex = (2+0j)
   Decimal = 2

 Выражение : "12 5 /"
       int = 2
     MyInt = 2
     float = 2.4
   complex = (2.4+0j)
   Decimal = 2.4

 Выражение : "-1 3 /"
       int = 0
     MyInt = -1
     float = -0.3333333333333333
   complex = (-0.3333333333333333+0j)
   Decimal = -0.3333333333333333333333333333

 Выражение : "1.5 3.7 + 2.1 *"
       int = Ошибка! 'Невозможно преобразовать "1.5" в int или неподдерживаемая операция.'
     MyInt = Ошибка! 'Невозможно преобразовать "1.5" в MyInt или неподдерживаемая операция.'
     float = 10.920000000000002
   complex = (10.920000000000002+0j)
   Decimal = 10.92

 Выражение : "2+3j -5-7j *"
       int = Ошибка! 'Невозможно преобразовать "2+3j" в int или неподдерживаемая операция.'
     MyInt = Ошибка! 'Невозможно преобразовать "2+3j" в MyInt или неподдерживаемая операция.'
     float = Ошибка! 'Невозможно преобразовать "2+3j" в float или неподдерживаемая операция.'
   complex = (11-29j)
   Decimal = Ошибка! 'Невозможно преобразовать "2+3j" в Decimal или неподдерживаемая операция.'

 Выражение : "2 3 ^ 3 %"
       int = 2
     MyInt = 2
     float = 2.0
   complex = Ошибка! Неподдерживаемая операция "%" для типа complex.
   Decimal = 2

 Выражение : "2 0 /"
       int = Ошибка! Деление на 0 при вычислении "2 / 0".
     MyInt = Ошибка! Деление на 0 при вычислении "2 / 0".
     float = Ошибка! Деление на 0 при вычислении "2.0 / 0.0".
   complex = Ошибка! Деление на 0 при вычислении "(2+0j) / 0j".
   Decimal = Ошибка! Деление на 0 при вычислении "2 / 0".

 Выражение : "1 2 3 +"
       int = Ошибка! Некорректное выражение - в стеке остались элементы.
     MyInt = Ошибка! Некорректное выражение - в стеке остались элементы.
     float = Ошибка! Некорректное выражение - в стеке остались элементы.
   complex = Ошибка! Некорректное выражение - в стеке остались элементы.
   Decimal = Ошибка! Некорректное выражение - в стеке остались элементы.

 Выражение : "1 2 + *"
       int = Ошибка! Недостаточно операндов для вычисления.
     MyInt = Ошибка! Недостаточно операндов для вычисления.
     float = Ошибка! Недостаточно операндов для вычисления.
   complex = Ошибка! Недостаточно операндов для вычисления.
   Decimal = Ошибка! Недостаточно операндов для вычисления.
```

Comment: спасибо, с этим разобрался уже сам)
вопрос, а как оцифровщик сделать? вот не понимаю, вообще

Comment: @bdc1 Добавил код со всеми изменениями.